# Does anybody know to derive the mediation effect?

Tags: self-study, multiple-regression, mediation

I recently read the paper **Imai, Kosuke, Luke Keele, and Dustin Tingley. "A general approach to causal mediation analysis." Psychological methods 15.4 (2010): 309.**

And I cannot catch the point of the derivation of mediation effect (see the following picture).
[image]
[image]

Can anybody tell me the detailed idea about each step of derivation? with any graph will be better~

Comment: What exactly is your question? $\delta$ is the average causally mediated effect and $\tau$ is the total effect, $T$ are the model covariates (conditioned upon), $X$ is the treatment, $M$ is the mediator, and $Y$ is the outcome taken to be normal distributions. Their expressions are probability functions relating differences in coefficients for logistic models for jointly normally distributed values when you do and do not adjust for the mediating variable $M$.

Comment: Thank you. @AdamO I don't understand what the H function is and why e2i is independent to Ti so we can write down the second equality.

Comment: $H$ is defined in the last display, e2 is independent of T_i because they are an error term and a covariate in the same linear model.

Comment: Thank you @AdamO. Have you seen this paper or used this method by the R package "mediation"?